# Why this setState is not a function in ComponenDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am trying to fetch ordered data from Firebase and set it to state highscoreArray but it gives error "undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.setState({ highscoreArray:sortedHighscores })')

```
    componentDidMount() {
    const reference = database.ref("highscores");

    // Pushing sorted data to highscoreArray.
    reference.orderByChild("highscore").limitToLast(3).on("value", function (snapshot) {
        sortedHighscores = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function (child) {
            sortedHighscores.push({
                "username": child.val().username,
                "score": child.val().highscore
            });
        });
        sortedHighscores = sortedHighscores.reverse();
        console.log("sortedh", sortedHighscores); // fetch success
        this.setState({highscoreArray: sortedHighscores}); // gives error
    });
}
```

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is.  Use an arrow function.

Answer (score 4):

One of the major advantages of arrow functions is that it does not have it's own this value. It's this is lexically bound to the enclosing scope.

```
class Logger {
  dumpData(data) {
    var _this = this;

    // this dumps data to a file and get the name of the file via a callback
    dump(data, function (outputFile) {
      _this.latestLog = outputFile;
    });
  }
}
```

// using arrow functions

```
class Logger {
  dumpData(data) {
    dump(data, outputFile => this.latestLog = outputFile);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1.this not accessible within loop so use variable `let that = this` the use `that` wherever you need this in this function.

```
  componentDidMount() {
        const reference = database.ref("highscores");
        let that = this // here your variable declaration
        // Pushing sorted data to highscoreArray.
        reference.orderByChild("highscore").limitToLast(3).on("value", function (snapshot) {
            sortedHighscores = [];
            snapshot.forEach(function (child) {
                sortedHighscores.push({
                    "username": child.val().username,
                    "score": child.val().highscore
                });
            });
            sortedHighscores = sortedHighscores.reverse();
            console.log("sortedh", sortedHighscores); // fetch success
            that.setState({highscoreArray: sortedHighscores}); // gives error
        });
    }
```

Hope this will help you :) happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `function` callback the `this` has a different context. Either use an arrow function, or store a reference outside:

Arrow:

```
reference.orderByChild("highscore").limitToLast(3).on("value", (snapshot) => { ... });
```